# How do I get a DISTINCT in this query

Tags: mysql

this is my query:

```
SELECT phpbb_attachments.attach_id, phpbb_attachments.post_msg_id
FROM phpbb_attachments
INNER JOIN phpbb_topics 
    ON phpbb_attachments.topic_id = phpbb_topics.topic_id
INNER JOIN phpbb_forums ON phpbb_topics.forum_id = phpbb_forums.forum_id
WHERE phpbb_attachments.is_orphan = 0
AND phpbb_attachments.thumbnail = 1
AND (phpbb_attachments.extension = 'jpg'
OR phpbb_attachments.extension = 'png'
OR phpbb_attachments.extension = 'gif')
AND phpbb_forums.forum_id BETWEEN 668 AND 679
ORDER BY phpbb_attachments.attach_id DESC
LIMIT 50
```

I want to get only the latest 1 attachment per topic.
So sort of like a distinct on phpbb_attachments.topic_id

Comment: table structures? (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`), and how to determine the latest?

Comment: what MySQL version do you have? Later versions have windowing functions that will form an easier solution.

Comment: attach_id is auto incremented so the latest is always the highest attach_id.

I can't post the SHOW CREATE TABLE because it's too large.

Version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gives the "best" attachment per ropic:

```
SELECT MAX(a.attach_id), t.topic_id
  FROM phpbb_attachments a
    INNER JOIN phpbb_topics t ON a.topic_id = t.topic_id
    INNER JOIN phpbb_forums f ON t.forum_id = f.forum_id
 WHERE a.is_orphan = 0
   AND a.thumbnail = 1
   AND (a.extension = 'jpg' OR a.extension = 'png' OR a.extension = 'gif')
   AND f.forum_id BETWEEN 668 AND 679
 GROUP BY t.topic_id
```

Then select attachments from that list:

```
SELECT x.attach_id, x.post_msg_id
FROM phpbb_attachments x INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(a.attach_id) AS attach_id, t.topic_id
  FROM phpbb_attachments a
    INNER JOIN phpbb_topics t ON a.topic_id = t.topic_id
    INNER JOIN phpbb_forums f ON t.forum_id = f.forum_id
 WHERE a.is_orphan = 0
   AND a.thumbnail = 1
   AND (a.extension = 'jpg' OR a.extension = 'png' OR a.extension = 'gif')
   AND f.forum_id BETWEEN 668 AND 679
 GROUP BY t.topic_id) i ON x.attach_id = i.attach_id
 ORDER BY x.attach_id DESC
 LIMIT 50
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Just had to add the order by and limit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! Also added the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses to the end of the accepted answer too.

Answer (score 0):

The id of `SELECT phpbb_attachments.attach_id, phpbb_attachments.post_msg_id` is not the same.

Now when you execute that Script even using `SELECT distinct phpbb_attachments.attach_id, phpbb_attachments.post_msg_id`, it will not generate a `distinct`phpbb_attachments.attach_id`.

The Reason is:
It will creating two distinct with this fields `phpbb_attachments.attach_id, phpbb_attachments.post_msg_id`

Now if you need a `Distinct` to this `phpbb_attachments.attach_id`

You have to do it first distinct:

```
SELECT Distinct phpbb_attachments.attach_id
FROM phpbb_attachments
INNER JOIN phpbb_topics 
    ON phpbb_attachments.topic_id = phpbb_topics.topic_id
INNER JOIN phpbb_forums ON phpbb_topics.forum_id = phpbb_forums.forum_id
WHERE phpbb_attachments.is_orphan = 0
AND phpbb_attachments.thumbnail = 1
AND (phpbb_attachments.extension = 'jpg'
OR phpbb_attachments.extension = 'png'
OR phpbb_attachments.extension = 'gif')
AND phpbb_forums.forum_id BETWEEN 668 AND 679
ORDER BY phpbb_attachments.attach_id DESC
LIMIT 50
```

then use `left join` to that particular Distinct Data using `phpbb_attachments.attach_id` itself something like:

```
 SELECT attach_id,post_msg_id 
FROM
(SELECT Distinct phpbb_attachments.attach_id,
FROM phpbb_attachments
INNER JOIN phpbb_topics 
    ON phpbb_attachments.topic_id = phpbb_topics.topic_id
INNER JOIN phpbb_forums ON phpbb_topics.forum_id = phpbb_forums.forum_id
WHERE phpbb_attachments.is_orphan = 0
AND phpbb_attachments.thumbnail = 1
AND (phpbb_attachments.extension = 'jpg'
OR phpbb_attachments.extension = 'png'
OR phpbb_attachments.extension = 'gif')
AND phpbb_forums.forum_id BETWEEN 668 AND 679
ORDER BY phpbb_attachments.attach_id DESC
LIMIT 50) as firstDistinct

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT phpbb_attachments.attach_id, phpbb_attachments.post_msg_id
FROM phpbb_attachments
INNER JOIN phpbb_topics 
    ON phpbb_attachments.topic_id = phpbb_topics.topic_id
INNER JOIN phpbb_forums ON phpbb_topics.forum_id = phpbb_forums.forum_id
WHERE phpbb_attachments.is_orphan = 0
AND phpbb_attachments.thumbnail = 1
AND (phpbb_attachments.extension = 'jpg'
OR phpbb_attachments.extension = 'png'
OR phpbb_attachments.extension = 'gif')
AND phpbb_forums.forum_id BETWEEN 668 AND 679
ORDER BY phpbb_attachments.attach_id DESC
LIMIT 50) as secondNotDistinct

On firstDistinct.attach_id = secondNotDistinct.attach_id
```